# Particles not appearing in viewport

Tags: particles

I am trying to make a missile. I want to put bolts on it to make it look a little more realistic. I was going to use a particle system to put them on there, but when I add the bolt in dupil object it doesn't show up. Help! [image: ???]

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse my ignorance on Dupil Objects function. However, you could possibly create a bolt mesh and use the array modifier to get equal distance across the body, both vertically and also across the circumference with the same modifier set to an 'empty'. that's how I usually create bolts

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to put bolt mesh onto the missile with the modifier? Kind of a noob with blender.

Comment: @GamerWiz there are many ways to do it depending on how you want it. do you want bolts running up the length? and do you want them going round it's circumference? also, do you wish to place some on the nose or tail? maybe a quick reference drawing could help, just the basic shade with some lines to show where you want them. And don't worry about being a noob mate, I'm not that much better and I've been doing this for 12 months